# How to add categories on a page

Tags: categories

I have multiple categories which can be associated with multiple parent categories.
How can I link one category to two parent categories?

Hi PortalP, - A sketchy work around is to add an empty category to the OTHER parent. And then you can add a redirect to the correct category. Let me know if you need help –
Can you please clarify and explain this more in detail? I am really new and don't have any knowledge in building a site.
Thanks

Comment: A sketchy work around is to add an empty category to the OTHER parent. And then you can add a redirect to the correct category. 

Let me know if you need help

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A category can have multiple children but only one parent. This was actually asked a while ago and was linked under your question. Check there for the full explanation.